# Protect computer from static electricity

Tags: power-supply, static-discharge

I have an issue with static electricity, that isn't so annoying as it is worrying.

When I'm cozy at home, I like to wrap myself in a blanket. Because of that, I build up a lot of static electricity. When I get back to my computer, it discharges and causes various symptoms:

- Almost every time, one of my screens (always the same one) turns off for 2-3 seconds then back on.
- Sometimes, my PC speakers start playing some noise, until I unplug the audio cable and plug it back
- Yesterday, I heard a loud spark and my PC speakers turned off. Fortunately I was able to turn them back on

That last symptom is what made me realize that it could be more than a mild annoyance and could actually damage my hardware.

I'm not actually sure what's happening, but my theory is that I build up static electricity (well, that part is certain) and when I sit next to the computer it discharges into the case (it's next to my leg), then into whatever is plugged to it (screen HDMI cable, speakers audio cable). I have one issue with that theory: my PSU is plugged to the ground, and from my understanding it should also ground the computer case because the PSU is screwed to it. Am I right to believe that the scenario I described shouldn't happen if my case is properly grounded? If so, how can I check that it's actually grounded? (I'm thinking a voltmeter between the case and a ground pin on a power outlet).

Comment: Apart from that, a search for "fabric softener anti static" will give you some ideas to reduce the static electricity.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - good idea. tbh, I didn't think there was anyone who *didn't* use it these days… but you never know. I have a couple of hiking thermal layers that specifically say not to use it, & they zap me every time I touch something. Nothing else I own does.

Comment: To piggy-back on @Tetsujin's great answer, a grounding wrist strap could be grounded to the back of the PC case and VHB taped/screwed to the bottom of the desk - touch a finger to it when sitting down _(a washer attached to the bottom of the desk, soldered to a piece of 18ga wire, and grounded to the back of the case would also work). The best solution is eliminating the source by reducing static buildup with fabric softener and dryer sheets _(purpose-built Bounce ones aren't needed, as any quality brand of dryer sheets will work, as you do get what you pay for when it comes to laundry care)_

Comment: @Tetsujin If fabric softener can't be used, there's a [myriad](https://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-Static-in-Laundry) of other ways to eliminate static, such as using dryer balls, spraying the fabric with distilled water before tossing in the dryer, washing/drying synthetic and natural materials separately, etc.

Comment: @Tetsujin Fabric softener is not exactly friendly to the environment, and it severely hinders the action of microfibre cleaning cloths. I don't need any of the advantages of synthetic materials for outdoor wear, so most of my clothing is cotton and thus I don't need to use fabric conditioner against static. But I do treat my laundry to those nice-smelling additives sometimes.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I use fabric softener, but I didn't know it could have an effect on static electricity. TIL.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I'm very fussy about my micro-fibres. They have their own cleaning fluid, would never even wash them with any other material, let alone put fabcon in. None goes in towels either. As for the rest, mainly cotton, but still gets the fabcon [the least smelly one I can find. I *hate* perfumes of any sort.]

Comment: @JW0914 I was hoping to control where the electricity discharges rather than preventing the build-up, but I guess there's only so much that can be done. Grounding something on the desk sounds like a good middle ground, I'll give it a try

Comment: @AndrewMorton Certain items should never have fabric softener used on, as it prevents the use of such items: dish towels/anything used to wash/dry dishes, any type of non-bathing cleaning cloths _(microfiber or otherwise)_, rayon/polyester blend fabric _(will cause the fabric to dramatically shrink by several inches, which is why Hanes XTemp undershirts state to not use fabric softener on them)_, etc. Microfiber cloths should be washed with non-lint producing fabric since they're a lint-attracting fabric _(washing microfiber cloths, dish towels, and undershirts in the same load works great)_

Comment: Something not mentioned in the comments - humidity.  I suspect your environment is very dry. If you can humidify the air it will reduce the ability for static to build up.

Comment: Just an update on this: I've bought an antistatic wrist strap and attached it to the metal frame of my desktop chair. Now all the static electricity discharges through it (I can hear the spark whenever I get back to my desk), even though I don't directly touch it. My screen and speakers aren't affected anymore, so I'm fully satisfied with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PSU & case will be jointly grounded [ie they're actually in metal/metal contact all the time] - but you need to check your actual mains plug & socket is earthed/grounded.
Some countries it's compulsory, some are a little more laissez faire about it all;)

The computer as a whole should be in effect a [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) - meaning any static discharge should run around the outside to earth.

Secondly… find a blanket that isn't made of man-made fibre. Similarly for shoe soles, as I imagine upgrading the carpet to pure wool is out of scope.
… or, from comments, use an anti-static fabric conditioner in your wash.

3rd, ground the desk or a metal plate on it & discharge to that first.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I tried a continuity check from the case to the ground pin of the PSU and they seem to be connected. I'll try testing the power socket. 
I thought the desk could indeed make things worse since the frame is in metal, but I found no continuity. I'm guessing that's because it's painted. Does it still make sense to ground it then?

Comment: Not for the sake of the desk, just as somewhere to discharge to before you get near the computer.

Comment: @KooKiz All PCBs are grounded by the screw points, which are a part of the ground circuit for the motherboard's PSU main header, so when the motherboard is screwed to a metal case, the motherboard, case, and PSU casing are all a part of the same ground circuit, which is earth-grounded via the PSU's AC supply line provided it's a three-wire _(don't rely on an outlet's three holes - test continuing between neutral and ground on the outlet, as they should have continuity; if they don't: outlet circuit is improperly wired or doesn't have a dedicated earth-ground, instead using the neutral wire)_

Comment: @JW0914 It is very common in households (at least here in NL) where only a few outlets are grounded. First thing I always do when moving houses is to get an electrician install ground outlets everywhere. And it is possible to insert a ground plug into a non-grounded socket and it works fine, except that static electricity buildup will not get discharged and this kind of shock and stuff will happen. EDIT: yes, seems to be the case for France too. Only ground in the kitchen.

Comment: @LPChip It's extremely uncommon in the US to not have earth-grounds for all wiring since the requirement was added to the NEC in 1965 and any homes lacking them here likely still have dangerous knob and tube wiring _(phased out in the 50s)_ - any upgrade of a home's wiring would require it to be updated to code in the US. Using non-earth grounded wiring at all is massive safety risk since it significantly increases the chance of electrocution because the user then becomes the path for ground if an arc or short occurs _(it's baffling why other countries wouldn't have similar requirements)_

Comment: @JW0914 The US also has earth breakers on many contacts whereas in the EU we have a centralized system. ElectroBOOM makes good videos explaining these. :)

Comment: @LPChip Do you have a link, as he has a lot of video results returned when searching for "ground" or "earth ground"? AC earth grounds are always centralized - in the US, the centralized location is within the main breaker panel, which is grounded to the earth via two individual pieces of 6ft rebar pounded into the soil near the main service entrance until they are buried far enough below the earth's surface that it meets code, providing a low resistance path to ground in the case of an arc or short.

Comment: @JW0914 https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plug-voltage-by-country/france/ and https://www.frenchentree.com/living-in-france/utilities/french-electrical-systems/

Answer (score 3):

Although there is already a good answer here, I did a little bit more research and decided an answer with this knowledge was warrented.

From your profile, I deduced that you reside in France.

In France, it is generally true that ground is only installed in the kitchen powersockets, not in the wall sockets everywhere else in the house. It is possible to let an electrician install grounded wallsockets elsewhere, but it has to be done.

France earthed sockets have two holes for + and - and a ground pin sticking out. This plug is not too different from a german SCHUCO one, which does not have a ground pin, but have ground slots on the sides. While there are some SCHUCO connectors with a hole for the ground pin, they don't always have metal contacts in the hole to actually make the ground pin work.

So you need to check that the wall socket is a grounded one with pin sticking out and that the plug in it has this ground pin insert. If this is a powerbrick that goes from one to multiple, ensure that it is a grounded one and that the pin is present on every outlet. Also ensure that the cable for your computer also has this ground pin insert.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer despite the accepted answer :) 
The house is recent (~15 years old), and all the sockets have a earth pin. Of course it doesn't mean it's actually grounded but that's very likely. 
I didn't realize before writing this, but the speakers power connector doesn't have a ground hole, I guess that's why they're affected. It's still a mystery why one of my two screens is also affected, but it's an old one so maybe it lacks some protections that the newer one has

Comment: @KooKiz Speakers only have a positive and negative wire to move the speaker's voice coil in and out and without shielded/twisted wiring, speakers will pick up the EMF generated by an electrical current and experience auditory noise due to the electrical noise. That specific issue can be remedied by using twisted speaker wire; for existing wire, splitting the wire down it's tear away groove, twisting the negative and power wire around themselves and heat shrinking both ends to lock the twist _(this is how quality aftermarket speaker wiring is done in vehicles, generally with a drill)_